# Не распознается javaScript

Tags: joomla, javascript

Столкнулся с эпичной проблемой, не работает java-script из хедера. В инструментах разработчика и в исходном коде файл есть. А весь код внутри него не работает. И в консоли ошибок нет.

Добавляется файл вот так:

```
 <script src="/modules/mod_cougar_contacts/javascript/contacts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Я пробовал даже заменить на пустой файл состоящий из одного алерта... Но ничего не вышло, и этот аллерт не появляется :(

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

P.S Joomla 2.5 добавление js файла реализовано её внутренними средствами (функцией JFactory).

Comment: Может Joomla! контролирует исплнение js? (например перед загрузкой)

Comment: а на прямую в адресной строке вызывается?

аля `http://вашсайт.ру/modules/mod_cougar_contacts/javascript/contacts.js`

Comment: нет, уже много раз делал так и все работало.

Comment: @Rules, не должна.

@HappyCougar, можете кинуть ссыль? + проверьте в средствах разработчика во вкладке "сеть", грузится ли он и статус должен быть 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему: требуется обязательное экранирование `jQuery` и событие `$(window).load(function(){` ко всему коду